# How to fix Application Gateway invalid probe path issue

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I’m creating an app gateway custom health probe and using the command below.

```
probePath=“/“
az network application-gateway probe create \
     --resource-group “testRg” \
     --gateway-name “testGateway” \
     --name “testProbe” \
     --path $probePath \
     --protocol Https \
     --host-name-from-http-settings true \
     --interval 300 \
     --timeout 30 \
     --threshold 3 \
     --match-status-codes "200-399"
```

This worked ok during the deployment last week but now fails with the error below

Probe is not valid. Path must start with a forward (/) and meet format requirements.

The same command works in powerShell but not in bash.
I’m using the azure cli task in Azure devOps

I am a bit stumped as it was working last week.

It also works in bicep templates but I don’t want to redeploy app gateway everytime I create a custom probe.

I initially changed the path to “/api/health and it worked but that’s no longer working.
I thought it was a bug at the time but now I’m not so sure…

I would appreciate some help please thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the results successfully like below:***

To create Application gateway custom health probe using CLI make use of below command:

```
az network application-gateway probe create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --gateway-name myAppGateway \
  --name myCustomProbe \
  --protocol Http \
  --host mybackend.azurewebsites.net \
  --path /health \
  --interval 300 \
  --timeout 30 \
  --threshold 3 \
  --min-servers 2
```

[image]

***Output***

```
{
  "authenticationCertificates": null,
  "autoscaleConfiguration": {
    "maxCapacity": 10,
    "minCapacity": 0
  },
  "backendAddressPools": [
    {
      "backendAddresses": [],
      "backendIpConfigurations": null,
      "etag": "W/\"fa1a1ab3-a497-44e1-9334-adbbdde37ccd\"",
      "id": "/subscriptions/124c97c3-58a7-4eb5-ac50-574aadc98e11/resourceGroups/imran/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/imragw/backendAddressPools/pool1",
      "name": "pool1",
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
      "resourceGroup": "imran",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools"
    }
  ],
  "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
    {
      "affinityCookieName": null,
      "authenticationCertificates": null,
      "connectionDraining": null,
      "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
      "etag": "W/\"fa1a1ab3-a497-44e1-9334-adbbdde37ccd\"",
      "hostName": null,
      "id": "/subscriptions/124c97c3-58a7-4eb5-ac50-574aadc98e11/resourceGroups/imran/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/imragw/backendHttpSettingsCollection/setting1",
      "name": "setting1",
      "path": null,
      "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": false,
      "port": 80,
      "probe": null,
      "probeEnabled": null,
      "protocol": "Http",
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
      "requestTimeout": 20,
      "resourceGroup": "imran",
      "trustedRootCertificates": null,
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection"
    }
```

***When I check in the portal custom health probes is created successfully like below:***

[image]

### Update

I tried the same script on Base and terminal its works successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

If still, your issue persists try to update your CLI version **`az upgrade`** You can check using this command  **`az --version`**

Comment: Thanks Imran, that solution works in powershell but not in bash. I’m using Ubuntu agents and unfortunately it still doesn’t work for me.

Comment: It’s a really weird one for me…

Comment: Hi @Missy I have tried the same it's working. kindly check the updated answer